# Setting selected option on init in AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs

When I try to set the selected value of a dropdown on init it doesn't work. Selected value is coming from a factory which is injected in the controller. But also when I make a very simple example it's not working, see: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cozvdue/2/)

```
<div ng-init="selectedItem1 = '2';selectedItem2 = '2';items=[{id:1,name:'One'},{id:2,name:'Two'},{id:3,name:'Three'}];">

<select ng-model="selectedItem1">
<option></option>
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value={{item.id}}>{{item.name}}</option>

</select>
{{selectedItem1}}
<br />
<select ng-options="i.name for i in items track by i.id" ng-model="selectedItem2">

</select>
{{selectedItem2}}
<button ng-click="selectedItem1=null;selectedItem2=null">Reset</button>
```

It's not working in both cases, using ng-options and using ng-repat.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it's not working"

Comment: What is not working? Why are you using ng-repeat and ng-options?

Comment: in the ng-init I set selectedItem1 = '2', but it doesn't select that item in the dropdown.

Comment: <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="item.id === selectedItem1" value={{item.id}}>{{item.name}}</option> // Try this...

Comment: Also, selectedItem1 needs to be a number. So get rid of the ''. eg...<div ng-init="selectedItem1 = 2; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-selected property to determine the selected option. Also, declare selectedItem1 as an int, not a string.

```
<div ng-init="selectedItem1 = 2; items=[{id:1,name:'One'},{id:2,name:'Two'},{id:3,name:'Three'}];">
<select ng-model="selectedItem1">
<option></option>
<option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="item.id === selectedItem1" value={{item.id}}>{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```